# How do I export data from my Outlook 2003 calendar for import to Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, outlook

I've seen some instructions on how to do it for 2007 but none yet that work for 2003.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about a  very old desktop application Outlook 2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really familar with Outlook, but a bit of searching suggests that its difficult or impossible to export the calendar from Outlook 2003. I see a few tools that people have written to do the job but I'm in no position to recommend anything.

What you could do is try Google's Outlook Calendar Sync tool, which claims to support Outlook 2003.

http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=98563

Answer (score 1):

There are instructions on exporting event data from Outlook and importing into Google Calendar here:
http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=83126